# basic bash syntax issue - syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, unix, syntax

I think my script does what its meant to do, at first I just had

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/parallels/Desktop/trashcan/*
    do
    echo "Would you like to delete - " $file 
done
```

I then wanted to add the obvious missing functionality so I now have

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/parallels/Desktop/trashcan/*
do
    echo "Would you like to delete - " $file
    read line
    if [$line == y|Y]
        sudo rm $file
fi
done
```

Thats where I'm at now, I did at first try to use a case statement instead of the if as I have a working script with the case statement I'd need but simply copying it over gives me the same error - syntax error near unexpeted token, I get this for fi and done

Comment: I believe you need spaces behind `[` and before `]`. And I'm not sure if the `|` or will work. Could you just try `[ $line == y ]`?

Comment: With the fix in either of the answers, this will still treat an input of "yes" or "Yes" as "no".

Answer (score 1):

`[` is a command, so it must be separated by whitespace from its first argument:

```
if [ "$line" = y ] || [ "$line" = Y ]; then
    sudo rm "$file"
fi
```

If you are using `bash`, you can replace the standard usage shown above with the more concise

```
if [[ $line = [yY] ]]; then
    sudo rm "$file"
fi
```

---

As Keith Thompson pointed out, only an answer of exactly 'y' or 'Y' will allow the file to be removed. To allow 'yes' or 'Yes' as well, you can use

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ $line = [yY]?(es) ]]
```

(The `shopt` line is only required for earlier versions of `bash`. Starting with version 4, extended patterns are the default in a conditional expression.)

Comment: THANK YOU! 
This works perfectly and I've learnt from this mistake, I appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

The if part should be

```
if [ "$line" = "y" ] || [ "$line" = "Y" ]
then
    sudo rm $file
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem. I had opened the .sh file in windows and Windows has added CRLF at the end of every line.

I found this out by running

```
cat --show-nonprinting filename.extension
```

E.g.

```
cat --show-nonprinting test.sh
```

Then, I converted it using

```
dos2unix filename.extension
```

E.g.

```
dos2unix myfile.txt
dos2unix myshell.sh
```